# Биты на C++ на примере кода.

Tags: битовые-операции, visual-c++, c

Люди выручайте нет ничего в инете о битах на `C++`, или еще их называют битовые поля.

Код есть, но не все понял.

Расскажите, что к чему, пожалуйста. Среда разработки `C++ Builder 2010`, если нужно.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

#include<iomanip>

using std::setw;
using std::cin;

void bit(int);

int main()
{
int x;

cout<<"vvedite сeloe x: ";
cin>>x;

bit(x);
getch();

return 0;
}
void bit(int x)
{
const int S=8*sizeof(int)-1;
const int M=1<<S;

cout<<setw(7)<<x<<" = ";

for(int i=1;i<=S+1;i++){
cout<<(x&M ? '1':'0');
x<<=1;

if(i%8==0)
cout<<' ';
}
cout<<endl;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const int S=8*sizeof(int)-1;
```

Это тип int включает в себя 4 байта, каждый байт содержит 8 бит поэтому множим на 8, а почему отнимаем 1? (ведь получаться 31 или нумерация идет с 0)

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const int M=1<<S;
```

Сдвигает биты первого операнда влево на количество битов, заданное вторым операндом.При выполнении операции сдвига правые освобождающиеся биты заполняются 0.
Это совсем не понял

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
for(int i=1;i<=S+1;i++)
{
cout<<(x&M ? '1':'0');
x<<=1;

if(i%8==0)
cout<<' ';}
```

Что делает вот это (мб только то что цикл пробегает 32 символа) но для чего. Ну вообще что то этот фрагмент вообще туплю. Не понимаю помогите понять.

Comment: @Atom, чтобы все это лучше понять распишите числа в двоичном виде. Например:

    x = 33 => 0010 0001

и нумеруйте биты справа налево (начиная с 0). в М пишу в двоичном виде результат сдвига единички.

Теперь проверим значение 0-го бита, 

    bitValue = x & (1 << 0);  => 1  M = 0000 0001

1-го

    bitValue = x & (1 << 1);  => 0  M = 0000 0010

5-го

    bitValue = x & (1 << 5);  => 1  M = 0010 0000

n-го

    bitValue = x & (1 << n);

Понятно?

Кстати, вместо `cout<<(x&M ? '1':'0');` можно написать просто 

    cout << (x&M);

только M надо в цикле перевычислять.

Comment: Но как х=1 сначала и как происходит проверка x&M в битах если деление не просходит(разве что компютеру известно что например 8 это 0000 1000) и в маске тоже 0010 0000.

Comment: @Atom, а при чем здесь деление? 

В **этом** примере `x` всюду равен 33 , а `M` равна сначала 1 (это 1<<0), потом 2 (1<<1) и т.д. Здесь всегда в `M` один бит в 1, а все остальные (31 шт.) 0.

Выполняется побитовая операция `AND` (символ `&`). Т.е. попарно сравниваются биты `x` с битами `M`. Нулевой с нулевым, первый с первым и т.д. В результате сравнения 2-х бит получается бит результата по такому правилу:

если оба бита 1, то бит результата 1, иначе 0. 

Когда образуются все 32 бита результата `x&M` то полученное **число, все 32 бита** записываются в `bitValue`. 

Понятно? (места мало...)

Comment: Извините за то что так туплю 
Ну вот давайте все по порядку 
1) const int S=8*sizeof(int)-1; - узнаем сколько бит нужно для целого без знакового типа так?
2) const int M=1<<S; - сдвинули 32 бита влево на 1 бит, если да то почему мы сдвигаем биты, почему не оставляем их на месте, как это понять?
3)x<<=1
if(x&M)
{
cout<<1;}
else
{cout<<0;}

можно пример по X<<=1? и как происходит все в 
if(x&M) тоже можно пример с вспомогательными коментами
Извините еще раз что заставляю ходить вокруг но что то реально не могу никак понять  :(

Comment: @Atom, давайте я Вам в ответе напишу (и видимо буду его дополнять), а то у меня комментарии заканчиваются, а в оставшемся (мне кажется) места не хватит.

Answer (score 4):

Операция сдвига влево - это, грубо говоря, умножение на 2. 
Дело в том, что компьютер представляет числа в двоичной системе (где есть только две цифры - 0 и 1). Поясню на примере. Допустим, у вас есть переменная размером в 1 байт, и в ней хранится число 10. Выглядеть. В двоичном коде это будет выглядеть так: 00001010. Чтобы понять, что это значит, нужно немножко знать о системах счисления. Вкратце эти нолики и единички означают, что ваше число имеет следующий вид:  0 * 128 + 0 * 64 + 0 * 32 + 0 * 16 + 1 * 8 + 0 * 4 + 1 * 2 + 0 * 1 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 8 + 0 + 2 + 0 = 10
Если применить к этому числу операцию сдвига влево на n позиций, то все его нолики и единички как бы сдвинутся на n шагов влево и мы получим вот такое число: 00010100, то есть 0 + 0 + 0 + 16 + 0 + 4 +0 + 0 = 20. То есть, сдвинув влево на один разряд, мы умножаем число на 2. Соответственно, если сдвигать не на один разряд, а на два, три, четыре и тд, то это будет умножением на 2 во второй, третьей, четвертой и тд степени. 
Аналогично для сдвига вправо, который представляет собой целочисленное деление на 2 в степени n, где n - число разрядов, на которое происходит сдвиг.
Операции сдвига с точки зрения производительности гораздо быстрее, чем соответсвующее умножение и тем более деление. Поэтому многие компиляторы по возможности заменяют умножение  и деление соответствующим сдвигом.

Теперь пару слов о выражении  cout<< x&M ? '1':'0'
Эта штука называется "тернарный оператор" и ее можно воспринимать как сокращенную форму записи следующего выражения:

```
if(x & M)
    cout << 1;
else
    cout << 0;
```

Здесь перед вопросительным знаком стоит условие (x&M), после вопросительного знака - результат выражения, если условие верно, а после двоеточия - результат, если условие неверно. 
   P.S. Кстати, << и >> после cin и cout не являются операторами сдвига

Comment: То же, что

    x = x << 1;

с таким выражением наверняка знакомы?

    x += 22;

Это то же самое, только операция не сложение, а сдвиг влево.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос но зачем мы умножаем на 2?

Comment: @Atom, один их ваших вопросов был (если правильно помню): 

    что такое  x <<= 1;

вот я и написал, что что сокращенная запись выражения

    x = x << 1;

А рассматривать это как умножение на 2 или сдвиг битов маски на одну позицию влево - это от задачи зависит.

Comment: Нет вы не правильно поняли или я не правильно выразился смысл вопроса в том зачем мы производим сдвиг то есть что это нам дает, для чего это мы делаем.

Comment: Что бы сдвигать биты. И на место самого старшего бита один за одним подвигаются биты слева. На них накладываем маску, что бы выделить только старший и потом, в зависимости от его значения, выводим.

Comment: Обычно это делается для проверки битов. Например:

      cout << "bits in decimal "<<v<< '\n';
      for (int i = 0, x = 1; i < sizeof(v)*8; i++, x <<= 1)
        if (v & x)
          cout << "bit "<<i<<" is set\n";

`x` сначала равен `1`, т.е. проверяем бит `0`, а потом этот бит вместе с номером проверяемого бита "бежит" по `x` к старшим разрядам.

На самом деле в этом примере переменная `x` не нужна. Лучше `if` написать так (а  `x` из цикла совсем выбросить):

    if (v & ((typeof(v))1 << i))

Тут мы говорим компилятору, чтобы он взял число 1 с той же  разрядностью, что и у переменной `v`.

Comment: Немного покопался еще, подумал. Перемещение 31-одного бита на 1 бит в левую сторону то есть число 31 то делим его на 2 получаеться 1111 1111 - это маска . А вот в for-е есть запись x<<=1 то если x целое без знаковое число для него уже зарезервирована память - 31 бит и происходит  проверка x/2 - if(x&M)если целое то 0 если нет то 1 и при этом происходит сдвиг на 1 бит и эта проверка длиться 32 раза. Я правильно понял?(в данной задаче).

Comment: @Atom, я совершенно не понимаю Ваших рассуждений о 31-м бите, числе 31, и делении пополам.

--

Еще раз про цикл for, x<<1 и печать битов. Все очень просто. Я описываю цикл **в своем комментарии**. Итак,

сначала x=1 устанавливает младший (нулевой) бит в 1, а остальные 31 бит переменной x в 0 (всего их 32, и в v, биты которой проверяем их тоже 32).

На первом проходе for смотрим бит 0, на втором бит 1 и т.д. Последним смотрим 31-ый. В конце каждого цикла единичный бит в x сдвигаем влево (x<<1), а операция v&x проверяет бит в v (тот бит, который установлен в x).

Вот и все. Никакого деления.

Comment: @Atom сдвиг влево на разряд эквивалентен умножению на 2. Сдвиг вправо -- делению.

Кроме того, во многих архитектурах есть понятия логического (знак -- обычный бит) и арифметического (размножается знаковый бит при сдвиге вправо) сдвига. В Си арифметический сдвиг не существует (так же, как и циклический -- со сдвигом через бит переноса или без этого бита)

Прошу прощения -- наврал. Размножение знака в C зависит от типа: signed -- знак размножается, unsigned -- нет.

Comment: то мы проверяем каждый бит в переменной x через цикл for так? а потом подвигаем его в лево7

Comment: @Atom Вообще-то у @avp значение в переменной v, а в x -- маска из единичного бита, которая и сдвигается влево. Сама анализируемая переменная не сдвигается.

Если типы x и v совпадают, то условие в for можно изменить:

       for (int i = 0, x = 1; x; i++, x <<= 1)

Answer (score 4):

Битовые поля -- специальные поля в структурах, которые занимают определённое количество бит, так что несколько полей могут занимать один байт (или не один). Родилось из потребности удобно описывать работу с аппаратными регистрами. 
В первую очередь ввода-вывода (кажется).

```
   struct myStr {
     int a:1;
     int b:2;
   };
```

Поле a занимает один бит, поле b -- два;

А может и просто для экономии памяти -- её тогда мало было. Аналог этого чуда в паскале -- packed record (ежели склероз мне не изменяет)

Comment: изменяет склероз. packed record это немного другое.

Comment: Пришлось гугла пытать, пытаясь реабилитировать свой склероз (и гугл сознался). http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Delphi/borland.public.delphi.language.objectpascal/2003-11/0463.html

packed records of subrange types

Просто на баг в компиляторе, связанный с битовыми полями я напоролся в своей единственной паскалевской программе (компилятор OMSI-II -- у меня тогда не было доков по нему). После этого я рабочих программ на паскале не писал.

Answer (score 2):

[@Atom](/users/3286/atom), отвечаю на вопросы:

`1`. `const int S=8*sizeof(int)-1;` - узнаем сколько бит нужно для целого без знакового типа так?

Нет. Количество бит в `int` это `S+1`, а `S` это максимальный **номер** бита в `int.`

`2`. `const int M=1<<S;` - сдвинули 32 бита влево на 1 бит, если да то почему мы сдвигаем биты, почему не оставляем их на месте, как это понять?

Да, сдвигаем все биты влево, бит 0 становится нулем. Например

```
x: 10010000 00001000 10101111 100000001 после x<<=1 превратится в
   00100000 00010001 01011111 000000010
```

Конкретно для нашего примера с S и М

```
S=8*sizeof(int)-1; // S = 31
M=1<<S;  
1:     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
1<<31: 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Почему мы не оставляем биты на месте? Очень просто, нам *это не нужно*.

Что мы хотим на самом деле? Мы хотим узнать значение бита целого числа в позиции **n** (например 2). Для этого мы хотим использовать  битовую операцию AND (операция `&` в C/C++).

```
v = 266  :    00000000 00000000 00000001 00001010 // видно, что бит 2 это 0
1        :    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 // число 1, будем делать 1 << 2
M = 1<<2 :    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100 // сдвинули
v & M    :    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 // число 0 т.е. бит 2 был 0
```

`3`. `x<<=1 if(x&M) { cout<<1;} else {cout<<0;}`

```
      for (int i = 0, x = 1; i < sizeof(v)*8; i++, x <<= 1)
          if (v & x)
              cout << "bit "<<i<<" is set\n";
```

Это печать какие биты числа `v` установлены (в 1). По шагам:

```
x = 1,  i = 0, v = 266
v:    00000000 00000000 00000001 00001010
x:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
v&x:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 // ничего не печатаем
x << 1, i = 1, v = 266
v:    00000000 00000000 00000001 00001010
x:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
v&x:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 // cout << "bit 1 is set"
x << 1, i = 2, v = 266 
v:    00000000 00000000 00000001 00001010
x:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
v&x:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 // ничего не печатаем
x << 1, i = 3, v = 266
v:    00000000 00000000 00000001 00001010
x:    00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000
v&x:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 // cout << "bit 3 is set"
```

и т.д. Все 32 шага расписывать не буду. Надеюсь теперь понятно. Что-то еще захотите уточнить - спрашивайте.

Comment: Если мы вводим число например 2 то компьютер знает его двоичное представление?

Comment: @Atom попробуйте ответить на детский вопрос: что такое двоичное представление числа 2? Это единичка и нулик на экране, бумаге или что-то ещё?

Comment: Ок это понял. А сдвиг мы делаем для того чтобы можно было проверить будет ли печататься 0 или 1?

Comment: @Atom, компьютер  видит, знает, работает и т.п. **только** с двоичным представление данных. 

Для начала, до изучения языков, почитайте что-нибудь об устройстве компьютеров.

Comment: ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ спасибо за ответы, терпение и отзывчивость всем и каждому. Отлично обязательно все это запишу. Ответы просто супер. Уже долго и давно искал информацию на эту тему наконец этот день настал. УРАаааа!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Также я бы еще мог порекомендовать Вам использовать специальный класс из библиотеки STL, которая идет с практически любой поставкой С++ (будь то MinGW, Borland C++ Builder, либо же реализация от Microsoft).
Этот класс называется bitset, чтобы его использовать, нужно просто подключить соответствующий заголовочный файл <bitset>, вот так:

```
#include <bitset>
```

Возможностей у него, к сожалению не сильно много (он скорее больше враппер, нежели полнофункциональный класс для работы с битами в переменной), но тем не менее, будете хотя бы знать, что такой класс имеется.

Answer (score 1):

[Битовые шкалы. Просто и понятно.](http://shatalov.su/ru/articles/algorithms/bitvector.php)